# ASP.NET Identity: Inheritance with Code First vs. Model First

Tags: asp.net, code-first, ef-model-first

I have been using ASP.NET Identity Code First and I wanted to check out Model First.

One thing that I have run into: how do I add something as a base class to an entity in Model First when the base class does not exist as a table?

For instance, with code first I can extend the **IdentityUser** as follows:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
}
```

But with Model First, it is only letting me choose things as the base class if they exist as an entity in the model - so how do I go about creating a User that extends IdentityUser with Model First?

Comment: MSFT apparently abandoned Model First and are now putting all their efforts into Code First. Now both Code First and Model First are half baked...

Comment: That is good to hear - I decided to focus solely on Code First as well!

Comment: Don't take that as gospel as it was just my own sarcastic opinion. Code First is also missing features that Model First has but it would have been nice if Identity also supported Model First and could be added to an existing project in a straight forward manner, which I have yet to find.